# C# Display SubTitles

Tags: c#

I Tried To Display SubTitles on the screen at the right time
now i got a exception

the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
class Program
{
    private static Queue<Subtitle> _subtitles;

    private static Subtitle _activeSubtitle;

    private static TimeSpan _currentTime = new TimeSpan();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _subtitles = new Queue<Subtitle>();

        Subtitle title1 = new Subtitle()
        {
            StartTime = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:06,000"),
            EndTime = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:07,400"),
            Text = "Enjoy the movie!"
        };

        Subtitle title2 = new Subtitle()
        {
            StartTime = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:07,500"),
            EndTime = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:09,500"),
            Text = "Hi, my name is Mary"
        };

        Subtitle title3 = new Subtitle()
        {
            StartTime = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:22,000"),
            EndTime = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:85,100"),
            Text = "Hello my name is John."
        };

        _subtitles.Enqueue(title1);
        _subtitles.Enqueue(title2);
        _subtitles.Enqueue(title3);

        Timer timer = new Timer(ShowSubtitles, null, 0, 100);

        while (_currentTime <= new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 30))
        {

        }
        Console.WriteLine("End");
    }

    private static void ShowSubtitles(object state)
    {

        if (_activeSubtitle == null && _subtitles.Count > 0)
            _activeSubtitle = _subtitles.Dequeue();
        Console.WriteLine(_currentTime);

        if (_activeSubtitle != null)
        {


            if (_currentTime >= _activeSubtitle.StartTime && _currentTime <= _activeSubtitle.EndTime)
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", _activeSubtitle.Text);

            if (_currentTime >= _activeSubtitle.EndTime)
                _activeSubtitle = null;
        }
        _currentTime = _currentTime.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100));

    }
}

internal class Subtitle
{
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Exception:

Timer timer = new Timer(ShowSubtitles, null, 0, 100);

'System.Timers.Timer' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments

Comment: Use System.Threading.Timer instead of System.Timer because threading timer supports callback method, dueTime, waitingperiod.

Comment: @Romil: OP is not using a WinForms Timer.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Comment: Fixed Tnx :) , now i got this one: String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.     . . in the line: .. Subtitle title1 = new Subtitle()
        {
            StartTime = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:06,000"),
            EndTime = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:07,400"),
            Text = "Enjoy the movie!"
        };

Comment: The TimeSpan could not be parsed because at least one of the numeric components is out of range or contains too many digits.

Comment: i fixed it Thnx EvreyOne! It Works!

Answer (score 3):

`System.Timers.Timer` doesn't have a constructor with four arguments

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

What you probably wanted was a `System.Threading.Timer`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to either change your Timer to a System.Threading.Timer or redefine how you use the System.Timers.Timer in line with its definition at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx.

It can get confusing as there are at least 3 types of Timer in C# - inside System.Timers, System.Threading and System.Windows.Forms!